# React.js: how to make a counter can not be reset when adding new elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when creating a new counter, it inherits

```
this.state = {
      count: 0
    }
```

I do not understand how to make that position maintained

I want to do when I add new elements, the counter save its position on the last item, please help
https://codepen.io/medonomator/pen/woKYzj?editors=0010

```
const data = [
    { id: 0, name: 'element'},
    { id: 1, name: 'element'},
    { id: 2, name: 'element'}
]

const appendItem = () => {
  data.push({
    id: data.length,
    name: 'element'
  })
  render()
}

class Counter extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) { 
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }

  }

  handleClick = () => this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});

  render() {
    return <span>
      {this.state.count}
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>+</button>
    </span>
  }
}

const ListItem =
  ({ item }) =>
    <li>{item.id} - {item.name} - <Counter /></li>

const renderListItem =
    (item, idx) => 
    <ListItem key={idx} item={item}/>

const List =
    ({ data }) =>
    <ul>
      {data.map(renderListItem)}
    </ul>

const ListContainer = 
    () =>
    <div>
        <List data={data}/>
      <button onClick={appendItem}>Add element</button>
    </div>

  const render = 
    () =>
      ReactDOM.render(<ListContainer />, document.getElementById('container'))

  render()
```

Comment: I tried the counter demo on Codepen and it works fine. Can you elaborate where the problem facing you is?

Comment: when I click on the element 3, assume 3 times, it is necessary that a new element 4 started with number 3, inherited from the previous one value and so on. Sorry poor English

Comment: This only for newly created elements? Or if you click to increment the first one should it bump everything after it too?

Comment: first we have 3 elements with the value of counter 0, suppose I clicked 5 times on "+" received a 5, then click "add element" and get a new item to the value of counter 5 by default, then clicked yet, suppose 6 times in the last element, in the end 11. Again click "add element" and get a new item with a value of 11 by default. Sorry for the stupid explanation (it is very necessary to resolve this issue. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: only for newly created elements

Comment: number should be inherited from the previous value

Comment: If you want new `Counter` to obtain the count value from the previous `Counter`, you have to keep track of that count globally.

Comment: As @xiaofan2406 says, you will probably need to keep that state external to your components. You may want to look into Flux and Redux as ways to help with that.